# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Not sure why but the RegisterStartupScript method is not available on my scriptmanager.  I am using System.Web.UI.

Comment: Could you post the exact error message and the relevant code?

Comment: which .Net Framework? Did you reference to proper DLL?

Comment: Any reason you can't use the ClientScript object of the Page instead?  Hard to say without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but maybe you should install System.Web.Extensions

http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the accepted answer didn't work for me.

My solution was that I neededto use `System.Web.UI` namespace.